# Как передать большой файл с помощью WCF? wcf Выдает ошибку 413 request entity too large

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

При попытке передать файл размером 81кб выдает ошибку, как увеличить максимальный размер передаваемого файла?

Вот код клиента:

```
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           byte[] image = null;
           FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imgLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
           BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
           image = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
           if (image != null && DataBank.CurrentUserId != 0) 
           {
               int Loaded = server.AddImage(comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, comboBox3.Text,image,DataBank.CurrentUserId);
               if (Loaded == 1)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("Изображение успешно загружено");
               }
               else 
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("Ошибка");
               }
           }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Вы не выбрали изображение!");
           }

       }
```

Вот код сервера:

```
public int AddImage(string imageTag, string imageRating, string imageDestiny, byte[] image, int CurrentUserId)
        {
            using (DBPhotoArchiveEntities DB = new DBPhotoArchiveEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    Images Add = new Images
                    {
                        user_id = CurrentUserId,
                        image = image,
                        tag = imageTag,
                        rating = imageRating,
                        destiny = imageDestiny,

                    };
                    DB.Images.Add(Add);
                    DB.SaveChanges();

                    return 1;
                }
                catch { return 0; }
            }
        }
```

Конфиг клиента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPhotoArchive" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:58094/PhotoArchive.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPhotoArchive" contract="PhotoServer.IPhotoArchive"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IPhotoArchive" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Конфиг сервера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!--Чтобы избежать раскрытия метаданных, до развертывания задайте следующим параметрам значение "false". -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!--Чтобы при сбое получать подробные сведения об исключении для отладки, задайте следующему параметру значение "true". Чтобы информация об исключении не выдавалась, задайте до развертывания значение "false". -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        Для просмотра корневого каталога веб-приложения во время отладки установите значение true.
        Перед развертыванием установите значение false, чтобы избежать раскрытия сведений в папке веб-приложения.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBPhotoArchiveEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PhotoDB.csdl|res://*/PhotoDB.ssdl|res://*/PhotoDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-G2ATPMP;initial catalog=DBPhotoArchive;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: перемудрили с чтением картинки `byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes(imgLoc);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась потоковой передачей. Всю информацию брал с этого сайта https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выставить параметр `maxMessageLength` в конфигурации `web.config` сервера:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxMessageLength="409600"
    executionTimeoutInSeconds="300"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" maxMessageLength="409600" executionTimeoutInSeconds="300"/>
  </system.web> 

Правильно добавил ? 
Говорит "
Предупреждение  Атрибут "executionTimeoutInSeconds" не разрешен.
"
"
Предупреждение  Атрибут "maxMessageLength" не разрешен. 
"

И выдает ошибку "Неизвестный атрибут 'maxMessageLength'. Названия атрибутов чувствительны к регистру."

Comment: Хм, странно. Старый какой-то совсем `WCF` что ли. Так то всегда как-то так эта проблема решалась. Таймаут не обязательно ставить, это так - до кучи.